# Android NDK socket connectivity issues

Tags: android, c++, linux, sockets, android-ndk

Ok, so I'm able to create a listening socket in my Android App using the following code:

```
bool CSocket::tcplisten(int port, int max, int mode)
{
  if((sockid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == INVALID_SOCKET) return false;
  sockaddr_in addr;
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  addr.sin_port = htons(port);
  if(mode)setsync(1);
  if(bind(sockid, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(sockaddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
  {
    closesocket(sockid);
    return false;
  }
  if(listen(sockid, max) == SOCKET_ERROR)
  {
    closesocket(sockid);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

I am then able to connect to it in the SAME process using the following code:

```
bool CSocket::tcpconnect(char *address, int port, int mode)
{
  sockaddr_in addr;
  hostent* hostEntry;
  if((sockid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        return false;
  if((hostEntry = gethostbyname(address)) == NULL)
  {
    closesocket(sockid);
    return false;
  }
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  addr.sin_port = htons((u_short)port);
  if(mode ==2)setsync(1);
  if(connect(sockid, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(sockaddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
  {
        closesocket(sockid);
        return false;
  }
  if(mode ==1)setsync(1);
  return true;
}
```

The problem is, I am unable to connect to other machines running a listening socket or on remote machines like google.com. Any ideas why I can't get it to work?

After some tweaking and probing, I found that the error occurs at the line:

```
if(connect(sockid, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(sockaddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    closesocket(sockid);
    return false;
}
```

The errno is 111 ERCONNREFUSED... Please. ANY help would be appreciated. The application has full Internet access set in the permissions.... Any ideas?

I have the same issues with my Linux build compiled with the same code...

Comment: Something that immediately jumps out at me is that in the `bind` call you use `sizeof(sockaddr)` when it should be `sizeof(sockaddr_in)`. Doesn't matter here since they are often the same size, but will be different if you start using IPv6.

Comment: You need to add code to get the actual error from e.g. `connect` when it fails. This is done by checking the variable [`errno`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) when the call fails. You can also use [`perror`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/perror) to print an appropriate error message, or [`strerror`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror) to customize the message printed. Check the actual error and edit your question to have it and it will be _much_ easier to answer your question.

Comment: Ok, Ill post the error code this evening. I would have included it, but I didn't know about it....

Comment: SO, the errno is 111 ERCONNREFUSED. After some code tweaks and stuff, I found that the error occurs at the line:

if(connect(sockid, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(sockaddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
  {
        closesocket(sockid);
        return false;
  }

of the tcpconnect method. Any ideas folks?

Comment: Please share which headers you included. I couldn't find `<net/net.h>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to connect to INADDR_ANY.  You want to copy the relevant part of the hostent into addr.sin_addr.s_addr.

Comment: For thos of you who want to see the fix implemented, go to my github located here: https://github.com/nterry/39DLL-4-Linux/blob/master/android-src/socket.cpp